# How to pass multiple arguments to a function in R?

Tags: r

So, I'd like to pass multiple argument values to a function and then get n-length output vector, so I could plot (x,f(x)) in R.
Here is the code:

```
f <- function(lambda) {
   sum((x-mu)/(1+lambda*(x-mu)))
}
lb <- (1-1/n)/(xmax - mu)
ub <- (1-1/n)/(xmin - mu)
lambda = seq(ub,lb,by=0.1)
```

If I try to just directly apply lambda vector to the function: `f(lambda)` I get just one value. If I try to `plot(lambda, f(lambda))` I get an error message:

```
Error in xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) : 
  'x' and 'y' lengths differ
```

How could I pass n arguments and get n-dimensional output vector as a result? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is `n` and `xmax`

Comment: `lambda` is defined at some length (we don't know but likely greater than 1), `f(lambda)` is returning a single number, and `plot` requires both `x` and `y` to be the same length. Perhaps `plot(lambda, rep(f(lambda), length(la,bda)))`?

Comment: How about `plot(lambda, sapply(lambda, f))`

Answer (score 0):

I will be guessing hard what you want to achieve. I hope I guessed it right.

```
library(tidyverse)


plotLambda = function(xmin, xmax, n) tibble(
  lambda = seq(xmin, xmax, length.out=n),
  `f(lambda)` = mean(lambda)/(1+lambda*mean(lambda))
) %>% ggplot(aes(lambda, `f(lambda)`))+
  geom_line()+
  ggtitle(paste("Xmin:", xmin, "Xmax:", xmax, "n:", n))

plotLambda(0,1,1000)
```

[image]

```
plotLambda(0,5,1000)
```

[image]